# ¿Deberíamos banear y quemar la etiqueta [script]?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, solicitud-de-quemado

Estoy mirando sus estadísticas de uso.

Hay 21 preguntas con la misma, de las cuales:

- 5 que son [script](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/script) y [linux](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux)
- 4 son [script](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/script) y [php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)
- 3 son [script](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/script) y [mysql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql)
- 1 son [script](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/script) y [batch](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch)
- 1 son [script](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/script) y [bash](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash)
- 1 son [script](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/script) y [python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)
- 1 son [script](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/script) y [javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)

y me debo estar olvidando de varias.... Pero se dan una idea que la etiqueta en si misma no tiene ningun sentido. Nadie la puede seguir porque no apunta a ningun lado. Y si apuntara a llamar asi solo a los scripts que se ejecutan por linea de comandos en un SO, para eso estan las etiquetas particulares de cada uno.

Por lo tanto propongo directamente elminar la etiqueta, ya que no tiene ningun uso claro.

(todo esto surgió porque vi que no tenia wiki, pero cuando quise armarle una, me di cuenta que no tiene un uso especifico).

Dejo varios links de ejemplos:

[Operador test en un condicional](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/90367/operador-test-en-un-condicional)

[¿Cómo extraer el contenido de un tag <script> con php?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/90013/c%c3%b3mo-extraer-el-contenido-de-un-tag-script-con-php)

[Consulta MySQL desde script](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/94873/consulta-mysql-desde-script)

[Script de bash en el que ingreses valor numerico y se ejecute con ese valor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/96164/script-de-bash-en-el-que-ingreses-valor-numerico-y-se-ejecute-con-ese-valor)

[Personalizar apagado del equipo [Windows 7]](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/106189/personalizar-apagado-del-equipo-windows-7)

[Como trabajar con un script en qpython sin salir](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/100178/como-trabajar-con-un-script-en-qpython-sin-salir)

[no logro que se ejecute el script cada 5 m](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/99418/no-logro-que-se-ejecute-el-scrip-cada-5-m)

Comment: Tienes demasiado sentido hermano, vamos invocando al Charmander :D

Comment: La idea de las etiquetas es poder ubicar un tema y seguirlo no? Si es generica, quien la seguiria si hay montones de preguntas dispares? Para mi no tiene sentido.

Comment: [tag:script] es una meta-etiqueta y como tal debería ser eliminada.

Comment: De [Creación de Etiquetas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags): "Las meta-etiquetas, aquellas que no tienen valor por sí solas, como la única etiqueta en una pregunta, no se permiten"

Answer (score 2):

## Generalización

La etiqueta `script` es general, y se puede combinar con cualquier lenguaje. Podría darse la combinación de etiquetas `script + c`, la cuál no debe ser tratada equívocamente sólo como `c`.

La etiqueta `script` es irrelevante y hasta trivial para lenguajes de programación cuyas implementaciones en sí lo hagan un lenguaje de scripting, no obstante no sucede lo mismo para lenguajes compilados como `c`, `c++`, `rust`, `assembly`, etc.

Sin ir muy lejos:

**prueba.c**

```c
#!/usr/bin/env bash
tail -n +3 $0 > temp; gcc -o out -Wall -x c temp ; ./out; rm temp out; exit

#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    puts("hola mundo");
    return 0;
}
```

Basta dar permisos de ejecución:

```bash
$ sudo chmod +x prueba.c
```

Y posteriormente ejecutarlo:

```bash
$ ./prueba.c 
hola mundo
```

El anterior código *C* es auto ejecutable, un script, la naturaleza del *C scripting* hace que todo el programa se escriba en un único archivo para simplificar la compilación, y lidiar con la carencia de algún *build system*. También tiene penalizaciones respecto al tiempo de ejecución, ya que aunque sea totalmente transparente al usuario, el programa se compila cada vez que se ejecuta el script.

Llegados a éste punto, el lector coincidirá que no es el mismo escenario el que expone las etiquetas `script + c` a sólo `c`.

## Respondiendo

> La etiqueta en sí misma no tiene ningún sentido.

La etiqueta `script` carece de sentido por sí misma, pero delimita y da contexto al dominio de la solución del *OP (AP o autor de la pregunta)*. Su uso indistinto e indebido es otro tema. Por ejemplo la combinación de etiquetas `script + c`, podrían generar preguntas totalmente objetivas como:

- *¿Por qué el **build time** de mi script supera X tiempo?*
- *Mi script no se autoejecuta.*
- *Los archivos temporales de mi script no se eliminan.*

> La idea de las etiquetas es poder ubicar un tema y seguirlo, ¿No? Si es generica, ¿Quién la seguiría si hay montones de preguntas dispares? Para mí no tiene sentido.

No, la idea de las etiquetas es clasificar y restringir el dominio de la solución del OP. También le sirve a *SOes* para archivar y clasificar el contenido del sitio, sea seguible o no.

## Conclusión

La existencia de la etiqueta es justificable, su mal uso es la que hace pensar o llevar a la conclusión de que no tenga sentido, pero vaya que sí lo tiene, y mucho.

Comment: De acuerdo a [Creación de etiquetas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) las meta-etiquetas no se permiten. [tag:script] es una meta etiqueta porque no tiene sentido como única etiqueta en una pregunta, siempre debería ir acompañada de una etiqueta de lenguaje.

Comment: @Rubén Hay un contexto en que esa etiqueta tiene sentido por si misma. Cuando una persona está creando un lenguaje de script nuevo. Pero no hay ninguna pregunta actualmente en que se de ese uso, hasta ahora siempre se ha usado como meta-etiqueta.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos: De acuerdo que en ese caso podría usarse sin embargo me parece que causaría confusión. Tal vez sería mejor usar [tag:lenguajes-de-programación] (aún no se ha creado)

Comment: Pero si una etiqueta por si mismo debe tener sentido, no seria mas fácil crear una así: `script-c` como ya existe para `sql-server` por ejemplo.

Answer (score -3):

## Debe quemarse

La etiqueta debe quemarse porque la palabra **script** del inglés al español significa **guión**. Esto no se refiere al caracter de resta `-`, sino que el guión es una serie de instrucciones escritas, como la planificación de una escena cinematográfica.

Eso significa que todos los lenguajes de programación son guiones, incluido *C*, *C++*, y no importa si es compilable o no, a fin de cuentas es un guión o un algoritmo.